# My css code in Word Press is working for every other page in the website when i only want it to work for 1 page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have currently made a code in CSS, which I wanted for a particular page but unfortunately, it is working for every other page as well and it makes the other pages look quite broken since the formatting of them goes very odd.

The solutions I have tried so far are:

Using the unique code of the page and making it something like this - * .post-id-17 .stop {code here}
But I got no results from using this solution.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CountDown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>CountDown</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <input type="number" id="seconds" placeholder="Seconds">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn start" id="start" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Start</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="continue" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Continue</button>
            <button class="btn stop" id="stop" value="0" onclick="check(this)">Stop</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="ok" onclick="toSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
* .post-id-706 .stop {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, #0045D6, #00A9f6);
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 13vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0045F6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content #seconds{
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #000000;
}

#seconds::placeholder{
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.7rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.start{
    color: #1f0;
}

.stop{
    color: #E00;
}

#start, #stop, #continue{
    display: none;
}

.counter{
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.counter');
const buttonsDiv = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const secInput = document.getElementById('seconds');

var seconds;
var remseconds;
var minuts;
var toCount = false;

function toSubmit(){
    display('start');
    remove('seconds');
    remove('ok');
    seconds = Number(secInput.value);
    counting();
}

function display(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block';
}

function remove(e){
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
}

function check(stat){
    if(stat.id == "start"){
        display("stop");
        remove("start");
        toCount = true;
    }
    else if(stat.id == "stop"){
        display("continue");
        remove("stop");
        toCount = false
    }
    else{
        display("stop");
        remove("continue");
        toCount =true;
    }
}

function count(){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(toCount == true){
            seconds--;
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
            minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

            if(minuts < 10){
                minuts = "0" + minuts;
            }

            if(remseconds < 10){
                remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
            }

            container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
        }
    }
    else{
        container.innerHTML = "DONE!";
        buttonsDiv.style.opacity = "0";
    }
}

function counting(){
    remseconds = seconds % 60;
    minuts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);


    if(remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }

    container.innerHTML = minuts + " : " + remseconds;
    setInterval(count, 1000);
}
```

If you have any ideas in order to solve this issue please let me know.

Comment: Plz enque this css only for which page u want.. Using body class or page id you can enque the css using if condition in functions.php

Comment: I am sure there should be any specific unique id/Class on that page you just need to find-out and target with that id/Class

Comment: Else, add the each every style before the body class.. like for example only for homepage, body.home {//styles//}

Comment: _“Here is the HTML code:”_ - _that_ is supposed to be from WordPress? I mean, not totally impossible, of course - but usually, WP templates contain more stuff, quite a _lot_ more. But at least `post-id-17` is not in there anywhere, so it is really rather unclear what exactly you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Post-id-17 is an example I am giving and the code has the actual reference to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the page where you want to apply CSS, and change all CSS with reference to that class.
for example:

```
<html class="some-class">
...<your code>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.some-class <your-selector>{
    <your css>
}
```

Comment: I will try this solution

Comment: Selector you are referring for the elements you want to apply the css 
for example 
instead of
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
you can right
.some-class .content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

Comment: so I have posted my code again, do you mean like that? @Raman Dhoot

Comment: The problem has almost been solved, now it only works for that 1 page but the button "Submit" does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a single CSS file with those contents to a single page, specifying a condition in PHP like so in the `<head>`:

```
<?php
    if (is_page(id-of-the-page)) {
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/stylesheet.css" />
<?php
    }
?>
```

Just make sure to set the correct ID of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="class2">
<head>
    <title>CountDown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>CountDown</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="counter"></div>
        <input type="number" id="seconds" placeholder="Seconds">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn start" id="start" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Start</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="continue" value="1" onclick="check(this)">Continue</button>
            <button class="btn stop" id="stop" value="0" onclick="check(this)">Stop</button>
            <button class="btn start" id="ok" onclick="toSubmit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
.class2 .content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.class2 html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
.class2 body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, #0045D6, #00A9f6);
}

.class2 header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 13vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0045F6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.class2 .content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.class2 .content #seconds{
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #000000;
}

#seconds::placeholder{
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.class2 .btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.7rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.start{
    color: #1f0;
}

.stop{
    color: #E00;
}

#start, #stop, #continue{
    display: none;
}

.counter{
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: The issue has been solved for my CSS working for other pages but now when i use the button "Submit" nothing happens.